# Expresión regular cuando no existe una palabra

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

Necesito hacer lo siguiente y es que en el código HTML de una imagen, cuando no tenga un `class="xxx"`, lo añada.

Tengo el siguiente código pero no hay manera de que funcione:

```
<img(.*?)^(?!class)(.*?)\/>
```

sutituyendo por

```
<img class="mimg"$1$2/>
```

Quiero que `<img src="url foto" width="20" heigh="34">`
Sea finalmente `<img class="mimg" src="url foto" width="20" heigh="34" />`

Comment: Pero ¿qué estás utilizando para realizar la sustitución? ¿alguna utilidad de tu editor de código?

Comment: Hola Asier, si era para realizar una sustitución en unos 1500 archivos utilizando Dreamweaver, lo solucioné con el código de Marcos.

Comment: @chelssi modifiqué tu pregunta para agregar la etiqueta [tag:Dreamweaver]. Las preguntas de [tag:regex] siempre deben indicar el lenguaje de programación o la herramienta utilizada. Más info en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: No habia leido los comentarios, ya reverti el cambio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la expresión `(.*)` habilita la presencia de cualquier cadena.

### Solución:

```
<img((?![^>]* class=))([^>]*)>
```

### Demo:

```js
// Reemplaza
var input = '<img src="url foto" width="20" heigh="34"/>';
var re = /<img((?![^>]* class=))([^>]*)>/g;
var output = input.replace(re, '<img class="mimg"$2>');
console.log(input);
console.log(output);

// No hace nada
input = '<img src="url foto" class="algo" width="20" heigh="34"/>';
output = input.replace(re, '<img class="mimg"$2>');
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Gracias Marcos, me funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Buena respuesta. El primer grupo es innecesario, `$1` siempre va a ser una cadena vacía ... Y marcaría algunos casos en los que fallaría. Ejemplos: HTML con comentarios, `<img src="unasteclassinletras.jpg"/>`, etc.

Comment: @Mariano, toma nro 3! :P

Answer (score 0):

Una buena opción, entiendo yo, es usar jQuery:

```js
$( "#imagen1" ).addClass( "nuevaClase" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="imagen1" src="url foto" width="20" heigh="34">
```

Comment: El autor no está usando JavaScript... Y si fuese el caso, ¿Para qué agregar una referencia a jQuery cuando se puede hacer [de forma nativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: Efectivamente. Así es.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que asigne la clase "mimg" a un elemento del dom, en adición a las clases que éste pueda tener de antemano:

```js
function addClass(elemento, clase) {
  var clases=(elemento.className||'').split(' ');
  if(clases.indexOf(clase)===-1) {
    clases.push(clase);
  }
  elemento.className=clases.join(' ');

}

var div1=document.getElementById('div1');
addClass(div1,'mimg');
```

```css
.clase1 {
  background:#CCCCFF
}
.clase2 {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

.mimg {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="clase1 clase2" src="url foto" ></div>
```

Comment: En vez de esto, creo que conviene usar [`div1.classList.add('mimg')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)... De todas formas, el autor no está usando JavaScript.

Comment: Lol, todos estos años y no sabía de la existencia de `classList`. Y, nuevamente, me equivoqué por no fijarme que la pregunta no es de JS. Damn